# Primes in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need a bit of help with this problem

Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ and suppose $x$ is prime, therefore $x$ is not a unit and cannot be written as a product of elements of smaller norm. Prove that $N(x)$ is either prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ or else $N(x) = p^2$ for some prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$.

thanks.

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer#As_a_principal_ideal_domain

Comment: For any nonzero nonunit $x\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ (prime or not prime), $N(x)$ is a nonzero nonunit integer, and therefore factors into integer primes. Since $x$ divides $N(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, we must have that $x$ divides one of these primes $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ (which need not be prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$). I guess from there you can finish if you use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is an integral domain.

Comment: Dear @JessicaB: This is a good comment which you should post as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Prime $\rm\:w\mid ww' = p_1^{k_1}\!\cdots p_n^{k_n}\:\Rightarrow\:w\mid p_i\:\Rightarrow\:w'\mid p_i' = p_i\:\Rightarrow\:N(w) = ww'\mid p_i^2$

Here $'$ denotes the complex conjugation.

Comment: nvm, thought about it and got my answer to my own question.

Comment: @Strider2 $\rm\ N(w) = ww' = n\in \Bbb Z\:$ is an *integer*, so it factors into a product of primes $\rm\,p_i\in \Bbb Z.\ $ Indeed $\rm w = a+b\,{\it i}\:\Rightarrow\: ww' = (a+b\,{\it i}\,)(a-b\,{\it i}\,) = a^2+b^2\in \Bbb Z.\ \ $

Comment: @Strider2 You should post your answer if you've solved it. That will help others.

Comment: oh no, I just figured out the portion where $N(w)$ can be factored into primes. Now I'm trying to figure out why $w|p_i$.

Comment: @Strider2 By definition, if a prime divides a product, then it divides some factor of the product. That's how I inferred $\rm\ w\mid p_i\ $ in this answer. Also, please don't overwrite your comment with a new one after someone has replied to it since then it makes the reply confusing (as above).